# ASP.NET не видит в Web.Config раздел system.serviceModel

Tags: asp.net

Добавляю ссылку на службу (WSDL адрес внешнего сайта из интернета). В коде, создаю класс из этой службы (клиент) - вываливается ошибка:

> Не удалось найти элемент конечной точки с именем "..." и контрактом "..." в разделе конфигурации клиента ServiceModel.

Создаю обычное консольное приложение, повторяю те же самые действия - работает, обмен со службой внешней происходит.

Смотрю разницу между Web.config (ASP.NET) и App.config (КонсольноеПриложение) - и разницы никакой нет в "system.serviceModel". Выходит что Asp.Net не воспринимает этот раздел в своей конфигурации.

Кто помочь сможет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалось в том, что запуск происходил через проект NUnit, поэтому этот раздел не видела веб-служба. Но остальные параметры приложения были видны.

Comment: Кому интересно, то добавил этот раздел в конфиг NUnit проекта и все пошло как надо.